# is numpy isclose function returning bad answer?

Tags: python, numpy, search

Using numpy isclose in the following example:

```
import numpy as np
np.isclose(1533761040,1533748023.0, atol=1)
```

Returns True, which is False.

Comment: Those two numbers differ by 13017, which is within the tolerance of 15338.  Why do you expect a different answer?

Comment: @JohnGordon why do you say that the tolerance is 15338 if I am passing 1 as tolerance?

Comment: See my answer for more details.  (the tolerance is computed from three factors, of which `atol` is only one.)

Comment: @JohnGordon your ans is clear, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) , `np.isclose()`uses this formula:

```
absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
```

rtol defaults to 1e-05, and you supplied a value of 1 for atol, so this works out to:

```
13017.0 <= 15338.48023
```

Which is true.  Why did you expect it to be false?

Comment: Found my way here because the pandas docs on [`pd.testing.assert_frame_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) and [`pd.testing.assert_series_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html) make no mention of the fact that these two tolerances are added - I had always assumed they were each applied, with the stricter of the two being enforced. This is a bit alarming... great answer!