# Unexpected passing test using atol and pandas assert_frame_equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unit-testing

I am trying to compare two dataframes using the testing library of pandas.
I do not want the values to be exactly the same for the test to pass, so I am using atol parameter.
Atol specifies the absoulte tolerance allowed. However, when the values to compare become high, the test passes even if the tolerance threshold is exceeded.

I hereafter provide two reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.testing

df1 = pd.DataFrame([42])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([41])
#This test fails as expected
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_exact=False, atol=0.1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([2006642])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2006641])
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_exact=False, atol=0.1)
#this test passes, but it should not
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? Have I misunderstood how atol works?

Comment: I also tried the similar numpy function (not sure pandas uses this under the hood). And I get the same unexpected result: `np.isclose([2006641], [2006642], atol=0.1)` returns `True`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that atol parameter is not used alone but in conjunction with rtol, which defaults to a value (1e-05), hence why the bigger values I was comparing made the test pass.

```
absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
```

In order to obtain the expected result, rtol also needs to be set.
In my case, in order to use exclusively atol, I need to set rtol to 0.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([2006642])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2006641])
#this test now fails as expected
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_exact=False, atol=0.1, rtol=0)
```

Credit to the answer in [is numpy isclose function returning bad answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804595/is-numpy-isclose-function-returning-bad-answer/51804735)